# Best placement of supply vents in a home

Tags: hvac, heating

We recently had an energy efficiency contractor visit our home, and they claimed the best placement of supply vents was actually the *shortest distance from the furnace*. According to their explanation, the air circulator should be pretty much *running continuously*, so regardless of the vent location, air would be mixing constantly in a way that heat would be evenly distributed. They also claimed that even large rooms really *only need a single supply vent*, assuming the system is designed correctly for the proper amount of air flow.

I understand that the conventional wisdom is that forced air supply vents should be placed in front of windows in order to provide a blanket of warmth from the exterior. Looking online, it seems like it's this is still largely considered best practice.

Is there any science to back up either approach? We are in a mild northern California climate, in case that is relevant.

Comment: Windows are usually the largest heat loss/coldest areas of a room, so heat vents are placed there to negate the heat loss.  Climate location is probably quite important if this needs to be followed.  Energy efficiently and a person's comfort level can be at odds if there is air movement/drafts.